# Alterar dados utilizando Checkbox - Php + MySql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Olá, estou montando um sistema de pedido interno e gostaria de incluir etapas de situação/status, estou tentando fazer isso em massa utilizando o checkbox.

Basicamente quero selecionar **x** numero de itens de uma lista, e transportá-los para outra lista. Minha dificuldade esta sendo em pegar parte dos itens.

Meu Exemplo: Tenho 5 itens no pedido, vou comprar apenas 2 hoje e 3 na próxima semana.

Formulário: gerar_compra.php

**Consulta para retornar pedidos em aberto:**

...

```
$resultado=mysqli_query($conn, "
        SELECT pedidos.id as id, data_pedido, produtos_c.nome as produto, produtos_c.unidade as unidade, qtde, data_aplicacao, local_aplicacao, solicitante, situacao
        FROM pedidos
        INNER JOIN produtos_c
        ON pedidos.produto = produtos_c.id
        ORDER BY 'id'");
        
        $linhas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
```

...

**Exibição da lista (gerar_compra.php)**

```
<div class="form-control input-sm">

<form id="select" method="POST">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Unidade</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Data Aplicação</th>
        <th>Local Aplicação</th>
        <th>Solicitante</th>
        <th>Situação</th>
                    
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <div>
        <?php 
            while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$linhas['id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".date_format(New DateTime($linhas['data_pedido']), 'd/m/Y H:i:s')."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$linhas['produto']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$linhas['unidade']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".number_format($linhas['qtde'], 2,',','.')."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".date_format(New DateTime($linhas['data_aplicacao']), 'd/m/Y')."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$linhas['local_aplicacao']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$linhas['solicitante']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$linhas['situacao']."</td>";
                                            
        ?>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $linhas['id'];?>">
                                                    
                <?php
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-default">Processar Compra</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    
                
    </tbody>
                
        
</form>
```

Porém não estou conseguindo pegar os dados da linha, estou tentado ao marcar as opções, (depois vou usar o update no campo "situação") e usando o "SELECT" para criar um novo formulário com a mesma estrutura acima, porém somente com os itens marcados.

```
<?php    

            $selecao = "";
            if(isset($_POST["check"])){echo "Os modulos Escolhidos foram:<BR>";
            // Faz loop pelo array dos numeros

            foreach($_POST["check"] as $modulo){
                echo " - " . $modulo .  "<BR>";
            $selecao .= $modulo;
            }
            }
            else{echo "Você não escolheu modulos!<br>";
            }
            echo $selecao. "\n"."echo selecao<br>";
            echo $selecao. "\n"."echo modulo<br>";
            
            var_dump($modulo);
            
            $comprado = mysqli_query($conn, "

            SELECT pedidos.id as id, data_pedido, produtos_c.nome as produto, produtos_c.unidade as unidade, qtde, data_aplicacao, local_aplicacao, solicitante, situacao
            FROM pedidos
            INNER JOIN produtos_c
            ON pedidos.produto = produtos_c.id
            WHERE pedidos.id = '$modulo'
            
            ");
            
            $comprados = mysqli_num_rows($comprado);
            
            ?>
```

Eu acho que meu problema é a linha na consulta "*WHERE pedidos.id = '$modulo'*" não traz todos os itens marcados, apenas o último.

Se alguém puder ajudar, acredito que para os mais experientes de bater o olho já vai ter uma solução ou indicar onde devo pesquisar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia colocar aqui o resultado da linha `var_dump($modulo)` ? 
Pelo que me parece, dentro do foreach de `$modulo`, na linha `$selecao .= $modulo` você está concatenando todos os módulos, sem virgula ou espaço. Isso provavelmente está fazendo ele não encontrar nenhum resultado no banco de dados

Comment: Esses são os resultados de 4 clicks. "Os modulos Escolhidos foram:
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
1234 echo selecao
1234 echo modulo
string(1) "4"